# How to create this model for Struts MVC?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, model

I have a college management portal. I have to create the following classes for depicting the model.

```
class Address
{
    String street;
    String city;
    
}

class Contact
{
   String phone;
   String mobile;
}

abstract class Person
{
   String name;
   String age;
   Address address;
   Contact contact;
}

class Student extends Person
{
   String course;
   String stream;
   String rollno;
}

class Faculty extends Person 
{
   String department;
   String faculty id;
}
```

Now should i use the getter-setter methods for instance initialisation or constructors?

What about the aggregation in class Person?

How should the constructor work there?

Comment: constructors are not alternatives for setters..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085141/about-constructors

Comment: Actually i don't want the user to know that i have used a Contact and address class in Person class. I just them to use the Student and Faculty class straightaway. So what should be the form of my constructor for Student class ?  I think i have to create a parameterized constructor which will have 9 parameters.[3 student class properties,2 person class properties, 2 Contact class props and 2 Address class props] . Am i right ?

Comment: As you mentioned you dont want you user to know the the structure of you class, you can have a Factory to create any person where you pass all information as parameter and then construct the required object to build person object. However I dont understand why you dont want the user to know about Contact & address objects.

Comment: Actually i was curious how that would work out !!

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think you should have getter & setter methods for the model objects. Your attributes of the class should be made private. 
The constructors are used to allow the mandatory information to be passed for object construction without which the object cannot be build (or the object is useless). Its like you cant create a person without name & age. In your case the address & contact many be optional. So you can set the address/contact information using mutator methods.

As Srinivas mentioned the constructors are not the alternatives for mutator method. 
The purpose of constructor is make mandatory things available for object construction. Its like without raw material you cant build a building.

Comment: Getter & Setter methods or accessor methods are called mutator methods.

Answer (score 0):

For this stuff these you need "beans" = private member variables with getters and setters for each. Depending on your needs you could create a constructor that has certain parameters to be set in the object at instantiation but also through the setters not directly (as certain setters might operate on the set value in a certain way so it is best that you do not mess up directly with stuff like this.student = "name").

For the faculty case I do not see why it extends Person and I do not think it should. As you say these are models they should reflect structures of tables in a database so at most each of them would extend an abstract class or implement a certain interface but not each other.

For the person aggregation also I believe that Contact And Address should be Integers as they represent a Foreign Key in another table and think about the case of many-to-many relation.

Models are first of all a reflection of the database in the application.

Comment: Model object are not necessarily be a table representation. They are used to store the information of a domain object or can be build to transfer information to other layers in the application to provide loose coupling.

Comment: The faculty has to there. and the database is going to be based on the model. Would it be best to use the constructor for Student class and Faculty class and give only the Person props and Student props as parameters ? And how do i call the Contact and Address getters and setter without letting the programmer who is using the code above get exposed to Contact and Address class.